# Jquery - unchecking all checkboxes when clicking a checkbox

Tags: jquery

Created a function in which on checking checkboxes it disables all other ones, but i am trying to uncheck all checkboxes except the one that had been checked.

The First if statement: if the 9th checkbox has been checked, remove the checked attribute from all others, and disable all others. Same with 10 and 11

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
                debugger;
                if (($("input[type='checkbox']")[9]).checked) {
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[9]).removeAttr("checked");
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[9]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                else if (($("input[type='checkbox']")[10]).checked) {
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[10]).removeAttr("checked");
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[10]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                else if (($("input[type='checkbox']")[11]).checked) {
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[11]).removeAttr("checked");
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[11]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
                else if (($("input[type='checkbox']")[12]).checked) {
                    $("#show").css("display", "block");
                }
                else {
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[9]).removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[10]).removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").not($("input[type='checkbox']")[11]).removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("#show").css("display", "none");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858612/how-do-i-tick-all-checkboxes-of-the-other-sections-by-ticking-a-checkbox-found-i/22867515#22867515) might help.

Comment: i have tried the prop('checked',false) but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.prop` to set checked and disabled properties on your checkboxes:

```js
var $checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"); // cache for better performance

$checkboxes.change(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      currentIndex = $checkboxes.index($this);  // get current changed checkbox's index

  if (currentIndex === 9 || currentIndex === 10 || currentIndex === 11) { // you may need to minus 1 from this as index is 0 based
    if (this.checked) {
      $checkboxes.not($this)
        .prop('checked', false)    // uncheck
        .prop('disabled', true);   // disable
    } else {
      $checkboxes.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="0"> 0<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="1"> 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="5"> 5<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="6"> 6<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="7"> 7<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="8"> 8<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="9"> 9 - uncheck and disable all<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="10"> 10 - uncheck and disable all<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="11"> 11 - uncheck and disable all<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="12"> 12<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="13"> 13<br>
```

Comment: once checking 9 for example, and then unchecking it still keeps all of the checkboxes disabled?

Comment: Works like a charm in the code snippet! I have transferred to my application, the disabled works but the unchecking doesn't work! i have had this issue previously and am not sure why

Comment: Nothing I am able to do unless you can create a [mcve] demonstrating the non working code.